# how to stop my app in Parallel Space?

Tags: android, security

I created an app. I want my one app only per mobile but i can create clone of my app using **Parallel Space－Multi Accounts**. So my question is how to stop to making clone of my app. Is android have any unique identifier, which is not alterable even if user reset the phone?

Answer (score 2):

I think there is not a way to prevent "Parallel Space" to clone your app, that is a problem about android system.

A simple workaround I use is to check whether the Parallel Space app is installed(ps package name: com.lbe.parallel.intl).

```
public boolean isAppInstalled(String packageName) {
    try {
        getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0);
        return true;
    }
    catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

As you can guess it is not reliable since many different apps can be used for this purpose. I didn't go further for my case but one thing that comes to my mind; if you have file write permission you can create a global file and put something there to check while opening your app.

Someone who knows how such apps work can provide better answers. If they are changing something in your apk while copying, then you can check those changes or hashcode of the apk, but it seems that they run your app in a virtual os, so this may not lead to a solution.

And there is not a successful unique id on android unfortunately. That is something I hate about android. I check different identifiers like deviceid, imei, mac address etc.. but parallel space creates new values for all of them.

Answer (score 2):

After I searched a lot for a solution to stop the app cloning, I came across this idea, which is to check the path in which the app data is installed on the phone.
The following code explains the idea further:

```
    int APP_PACKAGE_COUNT = 2; //----> my app package name is com.test.app the number is count of dots in package name

private void checkClonner() {
    String path = this.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
    int count = getDotCount(path);
    if (count > APP_PACKAGE_COUNT) {
        throw new RuntimeException("This app does not work in a cloning environment");
    }
}

private int getDotCount(String path) {

    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < path.length(); i++) {
        if (count > APP_PACKAGE_COUNT) {
            break;
        }
        if (path.charAt(i) == '.') {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```